# How would I dynamically bind a grid view with 3 drop down lists in c# asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

net gridview and I do not wish to use the built in controls and want to bind the data manually in c#. Could some one let me know where to start and how can I use 3 different drop downs to add more filtering?

```
asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server"  AutoGenerateColumns="False"  OnRowDataBound="gvContactorRowDataBound"  Gridlines="Vertical" >                  
                 <Columns >                         
                     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Full Name" SortExpression="contactname" HeaderStyle-BackColor="deepskyblue">
                         <EditItemTemplate>
                             <asp:TextBox ID="txtcontactname2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("contactname") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                             <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidatorcontactname2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Full Name is required for contractor update!" Text="*" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="txtcontactname2" display="none"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                         </EditItemTemplate>
                         <ItemTemplate>
                             <asp:Label ID="lblcontactname2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("contactname") %>'></asp:Label>
                         </ItemTemplate>
                     </asp:TemplateField>

                     <asp:BoundField DataField="phone" HeaderText="Phone" SortExpression="phone" HeaderStyle-BackColor="deepskyblue"/>
                     <asp:BoundField DataField="email" HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="email" HeaderStyle-BackColor="deepskyblue"/>
```

Comment: You said you do not want `Gridview` . So what is this code?

Comment: @FarzinKanzi i was just giving my front end code. Before I did gridview in the front end aspx page but I want to learn how to do it via the backend code cs page instead.

Comment: If you do not want built in controls, you can use loop. `foreach(var row in ...) div1.Controls.Add(YOUR-DROPDOWN)` .

Comment: @FarzinKanzi no the controls that I have in the code above are ok. I just do not want the easy way of binding the gridview  using the webforms designer page using sqldatasource and writing the query on the aspx page.

Answer (score 0):

You did not mentioned your scenario, therefore i assume that you want show all of students in grid view and in each row have a Drop down to select teacher. You have another data base `Teachers` and each teacher has `Id` and `Name`. So in your code behind you gathered all of the teachers:

```
protected List<teacher> teachers;
```

In each row of `Students` gridview you must have this column:

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Teacher">
  <EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" CssClass="selectClip" DataSource="<%# teachers %>"
           DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Id" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
        <asp:ListItem Text="<---Select Teacher--->"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
  </EditItemTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label ID="lblShowTeacher" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Teacher") %>' />
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

If you want to have your teachers in a `SqlDataSource`, change this:

`DataSource="<%# teachers %>`  to this: `DataSourceId="teachersDataSourceId"`